# Is there a way to access the user-defined setting without adding an entry to Info.plist?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to access the user-defined setting without adding an entry to Info.plist?

It's not logic for me create a setting in setting file and add an entry into info.plist.

This is my setting:

[image]

Comment: Why is it "not logic" for you?

Comment: There is no way to inject values into the compilation process in Swift, like you would in C & its cousins.

Comment: @Sweeper it think it’s not confident. In angular or laravel, you have one environment file and can direkt access to it

Comment: What is "indirect" and "not confident" about `Bundle.main.object(...)`?

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry for that but I need a good introduction how i can get the API URL in my Code. I cant find that, but all was i find was outdated. Im using XCode15.

Im a newby in Swift and XCode

Comment: You can either use a plist file or a `constants` object. If you are trying to keep values out of your repo, then you can use a build time script to inject values into a file that gets included in your app, but there is simply no way to provide directly a value to the compiler that the source code can use.

Comment: user means: "the app user"?